# Stackoverflow exception in java minesweeper game

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow, minesweeper

I was trying to make a minesweeper game in Java, but I keep running into this error. This function sets the current square to clicked and any adjacent squares to be clicked and continues recursively. It should stop when it runs out of squares, but even when I set the field size to 2x2 with 0 mines, it overflows.

```
public void setClicked(boolean clicked){
    this.clicked = clicked;
    if(adjacentMines == 0)
        for(mine m : adjacent){
            if(!m.isClicked() && !m.isMine()){
                setClicked(true); //Should be m.setClicked(true);
            }
        }
}
```

Problem solved, I was missing the "m." in my method call. Thanks to everyone for your help.

Comment: Not related to your question: I think you can ommit the `!m.isMine()` check - if `adjacentMines == 0`, this should not occur.

Answer (score 4):

You need to call `setClicked` on the adjacent mine, not on original mine, otherwise, you'll get `setClicked(true)` called over and over again for the source mine

```
public void setClicked(boolean clicked){
    this.clicked = clicked;
    if(adjacentMines == 0)
        for(mine m : adjacent){
            if(!m.isClicked() && !m.isMine()){
                m.setClicked(true); // setClicked should be called on the adjacent mine, not on itself!
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling setClicked on the same mine instead of the adjacent ones.

Change to:

```
public void setClicked(boolean clicked){
    this.clicked = clicked;
    if(adjacentMines == 0)
        for(mine m : adjacent){
            if(!m.isClicked() && !m.isMine()){
                //missing the "m."
                m.setClicked(true);
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can only guess that `setClicked()` method is a member of `mine`, but shouldn't you be calling `m.setClicked(true)` inside your condition instead of just `setClicked(true)`?

Comment: Ahahaha, thank you very much. I don't know how I didn't catch this.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to tell from your code snippet, but I would say you do not iterate over the cells. That means you are recursively checking the same cell over and over (to infinity and beyond *woosh*). The surrounding code would be very useful to see, though.